# How does Storm bolts interact with DataBase？

Tags: apache-storm

I am wondering how bolts interact with DB . As for my understanding from https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html , nodes like spout and bolt are in fact assigned to different work process and probably running on different machine, if that is true, how tasks in different machine form the same bolt manage to connect to the same DB ? Or do I misunderstand how storm cluster work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Each task of a bolt will just open its own connection to the database server.

Comment: I got it . Thank you